# What is the idiomatic way in Go to create a complex hierarchy of structs?

Tags: inheritance, go, struct, interface, embedding

I am writing an interpreter in Go and I am looking for the idiomatic way to store the AST. I read the Go compiler source code and it seems they used interfaces with an empty method to represent the AST. For example, we have the following hierarchy,

```
Object
--Immovable
----Building
----Mountain
--Movable
----Car
----Bike
```

This is how the above hierarchy is implemented in the "empty method" way.

```
type Object interface {
  object()
}

type Immovable interface {
  Object
  immovable()
}

type Building struct {
  ... 
}

type Mountain struct {
  ... 
}

type Movable interface {
  Object
  movable()
}

type Car struct {
  ...
} 

type Mountain struct {
  ...
} 

func (*Building) object() {}
func (*Mountain) object() {}
func (*Car) object() {}
func (*Bike) object() {}
func (*Building) immovable() {}
func (*Mountain) immovable() {}
func (*Car) movable() {}
func (*Bike) movable() {}
```

The above code is a contrived example and this is how the Go compiler [implemented](https://golang.org/src/go/ast/ast.go) the AST with dozens of empty methods. But WHY? Note how many empty methods are defined. It may get very complicated with the increase of the depth of the hierarchy.

It is stated in the comments that the empty methods disallow the assignment of incompatible types. In our example, a `*Car` can't be assigned to a `*Immovable` for instance.

This is so easy in other languages like C++ that supports inheritance. I can't think of any other way of representing the AST.

The way how the Go compiler AST is implemented may be idiomatic but isn't it less straight forward?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go is [not (quite) an object oriented language](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language): it does not have classes and it [does not have type inheritance](http://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance); but it supports a similar construct called *embedding* both on `struct` level and on `interface` level, and it does have [methods](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations).

[Interfaces](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) in Go are just fixed method sets. A type *implicitly* implements an interface if its method set is a superset of the interface (there is no declaration of the intent).

Empty methods are great if you want to *document* or *state explicitly* that your type does implement an interface (because it is not stated explicitly). Official [Go FAQ: How can I guarantee my type satisfies an interface?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#guarantee_satisfies_interface)

```
type Fooer interface {
    Foo()
    ImplementsFooer()
}
```

If you want a distinction in your type hierarchy (e.g. you don't want to allow an object to be both `Movable` and `Immovable`), they must have different method sets (there must be at least 1 method in each of the method sets of `Movable` and `Immovable` that is not present in the other's), because if the method sets would contain the same methods, an implementation of one would automatically implement the other too therefore you could assign a `Movable` object to a variable of type `Immovable`.

Adding an empty method to the interface with the same name will provide you this distinction, assuming that you will not add such methods to other types.

## Reducing the number of empty methods

Personally I have no problem with empty methods whatsoever. There is a way to reduce them though.

If you also create a `struct` *implementation* for each type in the hierarchy and each implementation *embeds* the `struct` implementation one level higher, the method set of one level higher will automatically come without further ado:

#### Object

`Object` interface and `ObjectImpl` implementation:

```
type Object interface {
  object()
}
type ObjectImpl struct {}
func (o *ObjectImpl) object() {}
```

#### Immovable

`Immovable` interface and `ImmovableImpl` implementation:

```
type Immovable interface {
    Object
    immovable()
}
type ImmovableImpl struct {
    ObjectImpl // Embed ObjectImpl
}
func (o *Immovable) immovable() {}
```

*Note `ImmovableImpl` only adds `immovable()` method, `object()` is "inherited".*

#### Building

`Building` implementation:

```
type Building struct {
    ImmovableImpl // Embed ImmovableImpl struct

    // Building-specific other fields may come here
}
```

*Note `Building` **does not add** any new methods yet it is automatically an `Immovable` object.*

The advantage of this technic grows greatly if the number of "subtypes" increases or if the interface types have more than just 1 "marker" method (because all methods are "inherited").

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I rethink my design for a non-OO language?

Comment: @unnamed_addr You mean for Go? What is the problem with empty methods?

Comment: I don't have any problem with typing more but I was thinking I was doing it the wrong way. That is the reason for me asking this question.

Comment: @unnamed_addr I edited my answer to show you a "technic" how to reduce the empty methods. This way you only have to write them once, and they are "inherited".