# Go OOP realization

Tags: oop, go

How should this code snippet look like in Go? How can I access to method of child class from parent class when child class is not defined yet?

```
class Parent {

abstract class MyParent {
   abstract function doSomething();

   function internal() {
       return static::doSomething();
   }
}

class MyChild extends MyParent {
   function doSomething() {
       return 'Test';
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go. Some related / possible duplicates: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251242/is-it-possible-to-call-overridden-method-from-parent-struct-in-golang), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622605/can-embedded-struct-method-have-knowledge-of-parent-child), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390736/go-embedded-struct-call-child-method-instead-parent-method), [four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144622/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-in-go-to-create-a-complex-hierarchy-of-structs)

Comment: The question what to replace it with?

Comment: Please read through all the linked questions+answers, they should give you some ideas.

Comment: I read it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As @icza said, there's no inheritance in Go (which is a sweet spot). The closest would be embedding a Parent's type.

```
type Parent struct {}
func (p *Parent) doSomething() {
    fmt.Println("Test")
}

type MyChild struct {
    Parent
}

func main() {
    child := &MyChild{}
    child.doSomething() // print "Test"
}
```

Check out https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

Answer (score 0):

```
//It's called interface
type Parent interface{
    doSomething() string
}
//Use interface before defining implementation
func JustPrint(p Parent){
    fmt.Println(p.doSomething())
}
//Define MyChild
type MyChild SomeType
//You do not have to implement interface explicitly
//Just to define method needed would be enough
func (mc MyChild) doSomething() string{
    return "Test"
}
```

Comment: But i can't use it like `MyChildInstance.JustPrint()`, only `JustPrint(MyChildInstance)`...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to accomplish, in the end, is something akin to the "Template method" design pattern:

> In software engineering, the template method pattern is a behavioral
>   design pattern that defines the program skeleton of an algorithm in a
>   method, called template method, which defers some steps to subclasses.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

AFAIK, the only correct way to achieve something like this in Go is to use interfaces as @pie-o-pah and @icza have said. I say "something like", because you cannot define methods with interfaces as receivers (i.e. there is no such thing as partially abstract type in Go).

A correct implementation would look like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// --------------------------

// define your purely abstract type as an interface
type MyParent interface {
    doSomething() string
}

// define a function (your template method) which operates
// on that interface; an interface cannot be a function receiver,
// but it can always be a parameter
func internal(m MyParent) string {
    return m.doSomething()
}

// define the implementation
type MyChild struct {}

// implement the methods for the interface
func (m *MyChild) doSomething() string {
    return "Test"
}

// in Go any type which implements all methods in a given interface
// implements that interface implicitly, but you can "force" the
// compiler to check that for you using the following trick
// (basically try to assign a an instance of the interface to a variable,
// then discard it)
var _ MyParent = (*MyChild)(nil)

// -------------------------------

// test code
func main() {
  m := &MyChild{}
  fmt.Println(m.doSomething())
  fmt.Println(internal(m))
}
```