# How to implement such kind of class hierarchy in go?

Tags: go, inheritance, overriding, embed

```
package main

type barer interface {
    bar()
}

// Actucally base is a complex type and it has dozens of
// membets and methods to make itself as a base.
type base struct {
    barer
}

func (b *base) foo() {
    print("foo call: ")
    b.bar()
}

// @Overide or virtual method.
// derive need to implement bar() individually.
// If derive didn't implement it, this defualt implementation
// can also be used as default.
func (b *base) bar() {
    println("base bar")
}

func main() {
    var d1 derive1
    d1.barer = &d1
    var d2 derive2
    d2.barer = &d2

    // bases works like a base manager who needs to manage dozens of
    // deriveN that have been registered to the []*base.
    bases := []*base{&d1.base, &d2.base}
    for _, b := range bases {
        b.foo()
    }
}

// derive1 embed base and will use the internals of the base
type derive1 struct {
    base
}

// @Overide or virtual method.
func (d *derive1) bar() {
    println("derive1 bar")
}

// derive2 embed base and will use the internals of the base
type derive2 struct {
    base
}

// @Overide or virtual method.
func (d *derive2) bar() {
    println("derive2 bar")
}
```

Here is [The Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ZzE9Wz3Eaab).

Yes, after read [Go embedded struct call child method instead parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390736/go-embedded-struct-call-child-method-instead-parent-method), i understood that my code can't work properly for "Go is not (quite) an object oriented language".

But, is there any ways to achieve such kind of class hierarchy or composition in go to make derive1 or derive2 to print derive1 bar and derive2 bar?

Further description of the problem:

For example, we want to create a window, but implement a window start from scratch is too difficult, at least we have to think about how to render it and how to dispatch all kinds of messages to different windows and are we going to use multi-threads or single-thread to handle it etc.

Some smart people who are good at render or scheduling or lock can implement the window base class, at the other hand we users can inherit it then implement some few services related methods.

In this example, base is just like the base window and deriveN is just like the simple derive window.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in your assumption that isn't quite the way. Here's my idea.

If we change the base struct and give barer a name, it'll be easier to read:

```
type base struct {
    implementor barer 
}
```

Now we should be able change:

```
func (b *base) bar() {
    println("base bar")
}
```

Into something like:

```
func (b *base) foo() {
    print("foo call: ")
    b.implementor.bar()
}
```

I think this should do what you want. You'll have some sort of virtual method that you're able to register on your base struct.

The Play link is here: https://go.dev/play/p/2mS9nRTaYTA

Comment: This really did what i want and we can instead use b.barer.bar() to achieve it, however it enforced my derive to implement the bar method which sometimes it doesn't need to implement, just use the default bar method that base has already implemented.

Comment: @api, you can still call b.bar() `if b.implementor == nil`. This is a pretty common pattern. Take a look at [http.Transport](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport), for instance. It has lots of optional function fields that replace defaults if set.

Comment: @Peter you are right. http.Transport used (*Transport).Proxy function field as "interface" to interact with user. At the other hand, (*base).implementor is always not nil, so i can use reflect package to check (*base).implementor, here is *derive1, if it has (*derive1).bar.

Answer (score -4):

> But, is there any ways to achieve such kind of class hierarchy or composition in go?

No.

You must model your problem without inheritance.

Comment: How is such a monosyllabic answer useful to a newcomer to Go? A modicum of empathy wouldn't go astray...