# Make object accessible in inherited method in golang

Tags: go, revel, object-composition

I am trying to implement inheritence in golang.
Below is example:

```
type A struct {
  Number int
}

type B struct{
  A
  name String
}

func (a A) GetNumber() {
    // Here I want to use instance of B
    fmt.Println(a) // but this is giving me instance of A
}
```

Is it possible to get instance of B in function of A if A is being inherited by B?

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go. Some related / possible duplicates: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251242/is-it-possible-to-call-overridden-method-from-parent-struct-in-golang), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622605/can-embedded-struct-method-have-knowledge-of-parent-child), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390736/go-embedded-struct-call-child-method-instead-parent-method), [four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144622/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-in-go-to-create-a-complex-hierarchy-of-structs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is an error in your code. Until you have not created another type defined as `String` you have to correct it to `string`.

Then in Go you can use composite structs, which means you can access a struct field included in another struct directly, as you already did.

This means that you can invoke a method on a method receiver which does have the struct fields declared. To correct your example, if i'm understand correctly your question:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    Number int
}

type B struct{
    A
    name string
}

func main() {
    b := &B{A{1}, "George"}
    b.GetValues()
}

func (b B) GetValues() {    
    fmt.Println(b.Number)
    fmt.Println(b.name)
}
```

In the example below because `struct A` is included in `struct B` this means you can invoke a struct field declared in `struct A` in the GetValues method. This is because `struct B` inherits the `struct A` fields.

https://play.golang.org/p/B-XJc6jddE

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question, as it asked how to get values from B in methods defined on A.