# avoid implicit satisfaction

Tags: go

How can I avoid implicit cast in Go?

for example:

```
type runner interface {
    run()
}

type person struct {
}

type program struct {
}

func (p person) run()  {}
func (p program) run() {}
```

If my intention of runner is only for person, not a program?
as you know, both person and program implements(satisfy) the runner interface.

Comment: Add another, "marker" method to `runner`, e.g. `implementsRunner()`. See [What is the idiomatic way in Go to create a complex hierarchy of structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144622/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-in-go-to-create-a-complex-hierarchy-of-structs/29145086?r=SearchResults#29145086)

Comment: A note on terminology: Go doesn't do type casting at all, implicit or otherwise.

Comment: Erm... it kind of defeats the point of go's interface system, and this example is  a hypothetical, but if your `runner` type is something akin to java's runnable interface, there's bound to be other methods that differentiate the two. A program must have IO, whereas a _"runner"_ could just be a thread (routine), which either doesn't communicate, or uses channels or whatever.

Comment: A question to ask that can help you differentiate: do both methods really make sense as having no return value?  For example, when running a program, it might return a status code on completion.  You can make a custom type for this status code so that an unrelated "run" method will have no reason to overlap.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit casting. Both structs satisfy `runner`, so both structs are able to be that interface.

If you are doing some conditional and you want to split `person` and `program`, you can always implement an additional method that only `person` will implement, but `program` will not. Such as [this (playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/MADOWtpipdF)

```golang
type runner interface {
    isRunner() bool
    run()
}
```

You might want to see this [GoByExample](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces) page which links to a great [blog post](https://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go) at the bottom describing what interfaces are and how to use them.

Comment: thanks, that's it. coding in go, needs a new mindset apart other langs ;)

Comment: Yes, the interface in golang is different than some other more traditional approaches for sure.